# Присвоение UIImageView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Нa view во весь размер располагается UIImageView играющий роль фона бекграунда. Задаю

```
   [[self backGround]image] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"1.png"];
```

Но получаю ворнинг о несовмстимости типов указателей (UIImage - NSString).
Где я неправ?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что должно работать именно вот так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[self backGround]image] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
```

[UIImageView Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [UIImage Ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImage).

Comment: Уже разобрался, хотел сам отписать. Спасибо!

Comment: Сначала в доки смотрите!